# Opencv and Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv

i am writing program in python. I imported opencv library. My code is as shown below

```
import numpy 
import cv2 
img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Anurag Bhai\\Pictures\\ll.jpg') 
print img.shape 

(256, 192, 3)     %% output of the above line %%

cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

This is the program above. when i am writing as cv2.imshow. The image box is opening and it is showing not responding

Answer (score 0):

Imshow() only works with waitKey()

```
import cv2
img=cv2.imread('C:\Users\Anurag Bhai\Pictures\ll.jp')
cv2.imshow('Image',img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: `cv2.waitKey(mili_seconds)`. `0` means wait until user close the `Image` window or press any key. It's also used to get the key that user has pressed.